# Android - How to send a notification (when the app is not opened) as soon as new data from nearby location enters the relatime database?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

As soon as the data enters the realtime database, I want to send a notification (with some data from the firebase, like title, description etc. that is posted to firebase realtime database) to the users nearby to the location(within the radius of 3 km) from where the data is posted to the firebase.

Till now I know how to get the data from nearby locations but I don't know how to send a notification (when the app is closed) as soon as new data enters the database from the user's nearby location..

If anyone know how to do that, please tell.

I have read documentations and saw demo apps but I can't figure out how to do that..

Here is how I am getting data posted in nearby locations of the user and displaying it in recycler view-

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("REPORTED-CUBS")
    geofire = GeoFire(db!!.child("REPORTED-CUBS-LOCATION"))

val r_cubs_al = ArrayList<DataModel>()

geoQuery = geofire!!.queryAtLocation(GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), 3.0)

try {
    geoQuery!!.addGeoQueryEventListener(object : GeoQueryEventListener {
        override fun onKeyEntered(key: String, location: GeoLocation) {
            try {
                db!!.child(key)
                    .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                            val r_cubs: DataModel? =
                                snapshot.getValue(DataModel::class.java)

                            if (r_cubs != null) {
                                rv_police.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                tvNoCUBSReported.visibility = View.GONE

                                r_cubs_al.add(r_cubs)

                                rv_police.adapter = ReportedCUBSAdapter(r_cubs_al)
                            }else{
                                rv_police.visibility = View.GONE
                                tvNoCUBSReported.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onCancelled(firebaseError: DatabaseError) {
                            println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.message)
                        }
                    })
            }catch (e : Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) service to send out notifications.

And the logic to automatically send out notifications, You can use a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) which will be triggered when new data is added to the database and that function will send notifications to the desired users as per your logic.

Comment: I am asking the logic only...like how can I send the notification to users who are there in the range of 3 km radius only...

Comment: I know about cloud functions and all but I don't know that how can I programme a function that will send notification only to users who are in the range of 3 km radius...

Comment: To achieve this there are prerequisites of it.
1. User's current location.
2. Center point from where you are gonna determine how far a user is.

1. Whenever user opens the application, you store his current location in database in form of Latitude & Longitude.
2. Center point you can define by your own (Latitude & Longitude)

Next step will be, a cloud function which will compare both, lat long of user and the center point and return a value which will be the distance between two points. Now you put a check on that value and trigger your notifications accordingly.